# ERROR: could not connect to the publisher: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql

I follow this tutorial and have a problem:

https://blog.anayrat.info/en/2017/08/05/postgresql-10-and-logical-replication---setup/

Error:

> (puslisher) b2=# CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub1 CONNECTION 'host=192.168.2.108 port=5432 dbname=b1' PUBLICATION pub1, insert_only;
>       ERROR:  could not connect to the publisher: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Can you help me?

Comment: Is this `host=192.168.2.108` the machine you are running your commands?

Comment: database b1 in 192.168.2.108
             
    and           b2  in  ..          .2.109